# Validation Rule for Currency field with Max 2 decimal places

Tags: validation-rule, regular-expressions

I am trying to create a validation rule for currency field which will take the maximum 2 decimal places only if you put the third decimal value it will should give you an error.

My currency field is having 16 numbers and 2 decimal places.

For e.g

Valid number - 12, 112.23,14.01,15.00
Invalid Number - 12.23455

Please find the below regular Expression which i am using in the validation rule

```
NOT(REGEX(TEXT(Amount__c), "[0-9]+[.][0-9][0-9]?"))
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
Amount__c <> ROUND(Amount__c, 2)
```

If there's a difference, this formula returns an error.

Comment: Is this even needed at all? Doesn't the field definition already constrain the values to 2 decimal places (I don't think rounding takes place, I think any extra decimal places given by a user are just straight trimmed out, even when updating from Apex)?

Comment: @DerekF Hilariously enough, no. The *display* is truncated to 2 digits, but you can still store many more than 2. I ran in to this problem once when calculating discount percentages in a custom app we'd build for the AppExchange (in a previous life). It's important that you either restrict the input via a validation rule, or fix it in a trigger/process/etc.

Comment: There are currencies that require 3 or even 4 decimal places.

Comment: @PhilW It's not even that, *all* number fields can store more than their designated decimal units. Never assume that what you see on the screen is what is actually stored in the database.

Comment: Ah, OK, I didn't realize that was what you were getting at. I hadn't spotted that issue myself, TBH, and will have a look see. Still, there are currencies that use more than 2 decimals :)

Comment: @sfdcfox I have applied this formula to validation rule but it is getting bypassed for each condition

Comment: @sfdcfox : Check with this regex NOT(REGEX(TEXT(Amount__c),"^\\d+\\.\\d{0,2}$"))

Comment: @ShantanuMahajan Yes, that should also work, I would think.

Comment: @sfdcfox It is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below regular expression.

NOT(REGEX(TEXT(Amount__c), "[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]?"))